# jquery pass radio button array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to pass the selected radio button value thru JQUERY and ultimately to php.

The following is the html markup:

```
    <li class="gchoice_1_14_0">
        <input name="donation[]" type="radio" value="25" id="donation" tabindex="14">
        <label for="choice_1_14_0" id="label_1_14_0">$25</label>
    </li>

    <li class="gchoice_1_14_1">
        <input name="donation[]" type="radio" value="50" id="donation" tabindex="15">
        <label for="choice_1_14_1" id="label_1_14_1">$50</label>
    </li>

    <li class="gchoice_1_14_2">
        <input name="donation[]" type="radio" value="100" id="donation" tabindex="16">
        <label for="choice_1_14_2" id="label_1_14_2">$100</label>
    </li>

    <li class="gchoice_1_14_3">
        <input name="donation[]" type="radio" value="350" id="donation" tabindex="17">
        <label for="choice_1_14_3" id="label_1_14_3">$350 - Guardian Angel Sponsorship – a donation at this level provides interview and follow-up services for one child</label>
    </li>

    <li class="gchoice_1_14_4">
        <input name="donationother" type="radio" value="other_amount" id="donation" tabindex="18" onfocus="jQuery(this).next('input').focus();">
        <input id="donation_other" name="donation_other" type="text" value="" onfocus="jQuery(this).prev(&quot;input&quot;).attr(&quot;checked&quot;, true); if(jQuery(this).val() == &quot;Other&quot;) { jQuery(this).val(&quot;&quot;); }" onblur="if(jQuery(this).val().replace(&quot; &quot;, &quot;&quot;) == &quot;&quot;) { jQuery(this).val(&quot;Other&quot;); }" tabindex="18">
    </li>
```

Then I am attempting to pass the data thru jquery so it can be caught via php. This is my present jquery markup:

```
        post_data = {
            'user_name'     : $('input[name=full_name]').val(), 
            'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
            'address'   : $('input[name=address]').val(), 
            'address2'  : $('input[name=address2]').val(), 
            'city'  : $('input[name=city]').val(), 
            'state' : $('input[name=state]').val(), 
            'zip'   : $('input[name=zip]').val(), 
            'ccnum' : $('input[name=ccnum]').val(), 
            'expmonth'  : $('select[name=expmonth]').val(), 
            'expyear'   : $('select[name=expyear]').val(), 
            'cardname'  : $('input[name=cardname]').val(),
            'ccvcode'   : $('input[name=ccvcode]').val(),
            'donation'  : $('input[name=donation]').val(),
            'donation_other'    : $('input[name=donation_other]').val(),
            'phone_number'  : $('input[name=phone2]').val(), 
            'subject'       : $('select[name=subject]').val(), 
            'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
        };
```

When I review the passing in Chrome's developer tools, the donation field/s are not being passed at all.

Could someone explain what I am missing with this? I have tried various ways of passing the donation value, but to no avail.

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, it's invalid to have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: That's the easy way out.

Comment: You're not actually posting data. You are just putting the values into variable. Check out this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Also this seems like you should just form submit the data. Why do you want to do this with Jquery?

Comment: because of the wonderful effects that can be done with jquery

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400490/how-to-pass-multiple-input-array-element-values-having-same-name-like-ex-sikll

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use jquery to get radio button value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043452/how-to-use-jquery-to-get-radio-button-value)

Comment: Just curious, but why even have the array style syntax in the name if you're going to manipulate the data with jQuery first? This doesn't have any benefits in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

For those who research and come across this post, the proper answer to my question is to detect the value that has been checked by doing this:

```
'donation'  : $('input[name=donation]:checked').val(),
```